# month as names not number in visulaizations

Tags: einstein-analytics, graph

months are shown by number like 1 is used for January. Is there a way to create a line chart of bar chart with the x-axis showing month (as a name) rather than a number?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have done this is by using a case statement to convert the numbers to the name of the month.

```
"q = load \"Dataset_Name\";
 q = foreach q generate (case when 'Month_Num' in [\"1\"] then \"January\" when 'Month_Num' in [\"2\"] then \"February\" ... else \"N/A\" end) as 'Month_Name', 'Dimension_1' as 'Dimension_1', 'Measure_1' as 'Measure_1';
 q1 = filter q by ...
 q1 = group q1 by 'Month_Name';
 q1 = foreach q1 generate 'Month_Name' as 'Month_Name', sum('Measure_1') as 'sum_Measure_1';
```

Answer (score -3):

You can either do it in SAQL, or you can also use the recipe to create an extra field, which is actually more scalable... This example is on Opportunity Close Date field.

1. Create a new Recipe (or update existing one) with Opportunity connected dataset as an input.
   Add a transformation node with the following custom formula built upon the field Close Date and save the outcome in a new field called CloseDate_MonthName:

```
CASE
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=1 then 'Jan'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=2 then  'Feb'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=3 then  'Mar'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=4 then  'Apr'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=5 then  'May'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=6 then  'Jun'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=7 then  'Jul'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=8 then  'Aug'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=9 then  'Sep'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=10 then  'Oct'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=11 then  'Nov'
    when MONTH("CloseDate")=12 then  'Dec'
    else ''
    end
```

2. On the dashboard, create a new column chart based on the recipe from the previous steps. As Bars use Close Date (Year), Close Date (Month) and the new CloseDate_MonthName field. Use sum of Expected Amounts for Bar Length. Because the field Close Date (Month) is there just for sorting, hide it.

You can also refer to this: [How to visualize month names in CRM Analytics](https://www.aboutsalesforce.com/2024/03/how-to-visualize-month-names-in-crm-analytics.html)

Comment: This site isn't a place for you to promote your own blog. The important parts should be reproduced here so that the answer can remain helpful even after your blog is no longer available (which is an inevitability).

Comment: You are right, have updated the answer to be useful without any link.